# AJAX request returning java object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I want my javascript to access an object which is returned from the java controller. However it fails and gives the error "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method." in firebug.
This is my javascript code.

```
var num = 1;
            $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/Myapp/ajaxtest",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: num,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
                //document.getElementById("tabtest").innerHTML = data;
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("ERROR!");
            }
```

and here is my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Plan> testingAjax(@RequestBody int num, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request) {
    List<Plan> plans = planService.fetchPlans(request,num);
    return plans;
}
```

When the program is run, it alerts ERROR!. Any help to figure this out is highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: it is most probably a problem with spring configuration not with client side.. so you should add spring and spring mvc tags

Comment: What if you omit `contentType: 'application/json',`? After all, you are not really sending JSON to the server and the server expects a number, not JSON.

Comment: Do you have jackson library in your classpath... also share your spring mvc configuration

Comment: ["The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."](https://www.google.com/search?q="The+server+refused+this+request+because+the+request+entity+is+in+a+format+not+supported+by+the+requested+resource+for+the+requested+method.")

Comment: I removed contentType, still no luck. @Arun: I don't have jackson library. but I have added Gson (com.google.code.gson) to my pom.xml dependencies. Won't it do same thing as jackson library?

Comment: @Nuwandi no... the default spring configuration will look for jackson library for json handling